# Modify existing query

Tags: postgresql, go, sqlx

I have two tables

```
create table jobs (
    id varchar unique primary key,
    account_email varchar not null,
    active boolean not null default true,
    enabled boolean not null default false,

    name varchar (50) not null,
    ...
);

create table job_tags (
    job_id varchar not null,
    tag varchar(50) not null,

    foreign key (job_id) references jobs(id) on delete cascade,
    unique (job_id, tag)
);
```

And this sql query to get job `SELECT * FROM jobs INNER JOIN job_categories ON (jobs.category_id=job_categories.category_id) WHERE jobs.id=$1`

Since I have little experience I perform one more query in order to load job_tags. Is it possible to create only one? I work with golang sqlx, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you almost got it:

```
SELECT * FROM jobs
INNER JOIN job_categories ON (jobs.category_id=job_categories.category_id) 
INNER JOIN job_tags ON (jobs.id = job_tags.job_id)
WHERE jobs.id=$1
```

Comment: The problem is that it actually returns more than one row, since there can me a lot of tags and I need to be able to load them into array, it is quite complicated. Maybe there is different approach?

Comment: Yes, you can use ORM (Object-Relational Mapper) like http://gorm.io that manages those associations for you